# Download excel file from an ArcGIS rest endpoint using R

Tags: r, rest, download, http-headers, arcgis

I'm trying to download the excel file stored at https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/b5e7488e117749c19881cce45db13f7e/data (website: https://www.folkhalsomyndigheten.se/smittskydd-beredskap/utbrott/aktuella-utbrott/covid-19/bekraftade-fall-i-sverige) with COVID-19 data on Sweden. The data is freely available and is stored on an ArcGIS infrastructure.

I tried with download.file() but the what is produced is not the excel but some unreadable file whose actual format is not clear to me. 
I tried to investigate the ArcGis Rest API but I couldn't find a simple solution.

Do you have any guidance on how to do this with R or with a general CURL/WGET based infrastructure?

Comment: The link to the file is indirect. I think you need to find the true link to the excel file or use a web client user-agent to 'simulate' a browser link click. In Python you can do this with the requests library.

Comment: Is there a way to find the direct link? I tried to simulate a click with phantomJS but no luck